# SQL command to search records and remove entire group if x is located

Tags: sql, db2

SQL DB2

This is what I have to start with

```
SELECT DISTINCT     
Last_Name, First_Name, State

FROM    AddressTable;
```

I am trying to modify the query to look through `AddressTable` and if `State = IL` then everyone with the same `Last_Name` should be filtered out.

If my results were below then I would want all of the records with last name Jones removed

```
Smith, Bob, MO
Smith, Eric, MO
Jones, Bob, MO
Jones, Eric, IL
Jones, Tim, NE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
    from AddressTable 
    where Last_Name not in 
        (
        select Last_Name 
        from AddressTable
        where State = 'IL'
        )
```

Comment: For this kind of `DELETE` statement, you won't need `DISTINCT` (and that clause as part of an `IN` clause is meaningless too).  However, I'm pretty sure the OP is simply looking to _not include_ records in the `SELECT` result set, not actually remove them from the source table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on whether you want to delete rows, or if you just want to filter rows. Here rows are filtered:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Last_Name, First_Name, State
FROM    AddressTable X
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM AddressTable Y
    WHERE X.NAME = Y.NAME 
      AND Y.STATE = 'IL'
);
```